# Angular Material Design icons for each letter in the alphabet

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, material-design-icons

I can't find any angular material icons for each letter in the alphabet  [here](https://design.google.com/icons/) and [here](https://materialdesignicons.com/) specially for "R", "A" and "V".

I want to have the following icons like below. A plain circle with a capital letter inside.

[image]

*I just crop this one.*

I am now suggesting it in [MaterialDesign](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign/issues/1332) Git hub.

**Update**

I search on hoping to find and I found [one](http://tonight-app.fr/php/users/cocktailsList.php?name=gin) of my liking but I want is an SVG only not png, jpg, etc.

And this [one](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable) is android not Angular-material icon.

Comment: Make them yourself as .png and then go to one of the many free online converters and convert your png's to icons

Comment: Thanks @Dominofoe, i tried using an online designer tool instead http://editor.method.ac/. Since online converters doesn't give out what I want

Answer (score 1):

Over at [material design icons](http://materialdesignicons.com) we now have a full set of [alphanumeric icons](http://materialdesignicons.com/tag/alpha-numeric). These may handle your use case but we always suggest using a standard font such as Roboto where possible to better match your existing font choices.

[image]